# Conversion Error setting value '01/2016' for 'null Converter' in JSF?

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, javabeans

I have an requirement to add month picker in JSF, previously we are using calender component of primefaces. But here we need month picker, so I am using jQuery month picker plugin. The code I have used are as follows

```
$('.startDate').Monthpicker({
        onSelect: function () {
            $('.endDate').Monthpicker('option', { minValue: $('.startDate').val() });
        }
    });
    $('.endDate').Monthpicker({
        onSelect: function () {
            $('.startDate').Monthpicker('option', { maxValue: $('.endDate').val() });
        }
    });
```

In XHTML Page

```
<h:outputText value="From :"/>
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.fromDate}" styleClass="startDate" />
<h:outputText value=" To :"/>
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.toDate}" styleClass="endDate" />
```

When I am submitting the form, I am getting this error.

Conversion Error setting value '01/2016' for 'null Converter'.
Conversion Error setting value '02/2016' for 'null Converter'.